# LED (AES like) algorithm Decryption-Mixcolumn

Tags: aes, block-cipher, finite-field

I want to program decryption algorithm for the LED cipher.
The lightweight block cipher LED(Jian Guo, Thomas Peyrin, Axel Poschmann, Matt Robshaw:CHES 2011).
All the things is routine except the MixColumn component which is like the MixColumn of AES but with a different matrix.
 In fact we have 64 bit of plain text in structure of a state[4][4].
In the MixColumn component each column of the state multiplies with the matrix M  and the result will be replaced with the old column(in the encryption process)

[image]

I wanna to have decryption so I need ReverseMixcolumn function.For that i need the inverted matrix M which I have no idea about calculating it.
I know nothing about calculating matrix inverse in the field of operation.
Even I dont know what is the field of operation in algorithm hence it is not pronounced in paper(eprint.iacr.org/2012/600.pdf)

This is code of MixColumn component:

```
const unsigned char MixColMatrix[4][4] =
{
    { 4,  1, 2, 2 },
    { 8,  6, 5, 6 },
    { 11,14,10, 9 },
    { 2,  2,15,11 },
};
void MixColumn(unsigned char state[4][4])
{
    int i, j, k;
    unsigned char tmp[4];
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) //j=0 soton 0 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {
            unsigned char sum = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                sum ^= FieldMult(MixColMatrix[i][k], state[k][j]);
            tmp[i] = sum;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) //taaghir sotoon
            state[i][j] = tmp[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of LED MDS matrix is :

$$\left[
\begin{array}{c c c c}
12 & 12 & 13 & 4 \\
3 & 8 & 4 & 5\\
7 & 6 & 2 & 14\\
13 & 9 & 9 & 13\\
\end{array}\right]$$

you can verify it.

this is sage code that generates the inverse MDS matrix.

```
f=x^4+x^1+1  # irrudiciable polynomial
L.<z>= GF(2^4,modulus=f)
R=PolynomialRing(L,'x')
N=16
m=[(4,  1, 2, 2),(8,  6, 5, 6),(11,14,10, 9),(2,  2,15,11)]
T= matrix(m)
#print S.inverse()
print m
print T
P=matrix(L,4,4)
P_1=matrix(L,4,4)
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        P[i,j]= (T[i][j]) + z^1*(T[i][j]>>1) + z^2*(T[i][j]>>2) + z^3*(T[i][j]>>3)



print P
P_1=P.inverse()
print P_1
# print the matrix with clear distance
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        print P_1[i,j]
    print ""
```

Answer (score 1):

## The field

We're using a polynomial field here, where the nibbles (four-bit values) are coefficients to a 3th degree polynomial. As such, the $4$ in your matrix signifies $X^2$, the $B$ in your matrix signifies $X^3 + X + 1$. Operations are done over those polynomials. For example, $4+4 = X^2 + X^2 = 0$; note that addition can be trivially implemented using XOR (and thus subtraction and addition are equivalent).

Secondly, we note that we're *actually* working in a quotient ring, with modulus $P[X]=X^4+X+1$, which practically means that when we "overflow" beyond $X^4$ in our operation, we take the remainder modulo $P$. Since our modulus is irreducible, we have a field (with inversion). For example $4\times 4 = X^4 \pmod P = X+1 = 3$.

$z^{-1}$ is the inverse of $z$ if $z\cdot z^{-1} = 1 \mod P$. One way to compute this inverse is using the [extended Euclidian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Simple_algebraic_field_extensions).

## Matrix inversion

There are many ways to compute the matrix inverse, but the most "secondary school" way is probably [Gauss-Jordan elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix). You start by writing $[M|I_n]$:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c c c c | c c c c}
4 & 1 & 2 & 2  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
8 & 6 & 5 & 6  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
B & E & A & 9  & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & F & B  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

And then you reduce this matrix to the form $[I_n|M^{-1}]$. There's one "but" in this story: you have to keep in mind that you are working with polynomials modulo $P$. Let us create a zero on the second row $r_2$. We note that we're lucky: $4\times 2 = X^2 \cdot X^1 = X^3 = 8$, so we can subtract $2\times r_1$ from row $r_2$. Subtraction is just a XOR operation, so we get

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c c c c | c c c c}
4 & 1 & 2 & 2  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 4 & 1 & 2  & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
B & E & A & 9  & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & F & B  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Next up, you might want to get a 1 as first element of $r_1$, that's where you multiply the first row with the inverse of $4$. I inverted $4$ on paper, and I hope I didn't make any mistakes. $4\times 12 = x^2 \cdot (x^3 + x^2) \pmod P = 1$, so you would multiply $r_1$ with $12 \pmod P$.

---

Now, to do this by hand, it takes a while. That's where [hardyrama's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60226/48404) comes in: a computer can do this way faster. But at least now you know how you could do it!

P.S.: please be kind to any arithmetic errors. I used pen and paper, and I'm know for those mistakes :-)