# aes invmixcolumns process?

Tags: aes

I want to know how to obtain

mixcolum -> invmixcolumns

mixcolumn = [2 3 1 1
             1 2 3 1
             1 1 2 3
             3 1 1 2 ]
->

-1/35 [4 3 11 17
       17 4 3 11
       11 17 4 3
       3  11 17 4]

-> [0e 0b 0d 09
    09 0e 0b 0d
    0d 09 0e 0b
    0b 0d 09 0e]

why ?

[0e 0b 0d 09
    09 0e 0b 0d
    0d 09 0e 0b
    0b 0d 09 0e]

Comment: This similar question might give you idea how to compute the inverse : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44437/led-aes-like-algorithm-decryption-mixcolumn/60226#60226

Answer (score 1):

Each byte represents an element of a the finite field $\mathbf F_{256}$ with modulus $x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$.

For example, the byte $0x0e$ correspond to the polynomial $x^3 + x^2 + x$. Each coefficient of the polynomials are either 0 or 1. When you multiply two polynomials, we can always reduce by the modulus, so we end up with a polynomial of degree at most 7, so $8$ binary coefficients: a byte.

Now that we are done with the preliminaries, we can look at of the MixColumn operation works in AES.

Suppose we have a column consisting of 4 bytes, $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. MixColumn is a linear invertible operation that change the bytes to $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ by multiplying the column by an invertible matrix $M$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
02 & 03 & 01 & 01 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 01 \\
01 & 01 & 02 & 03 \\
03 & 01 & 01 & 02
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
A \\ B \\ C \\ D
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
And do not forget that the bytes $0x01$, $0x02$ and $0x03$ represents respectively the polynomials $1$, $x$ and $x+1$, so we have $A = xa + (x+1) b + c + d$.

InvMixColumns is the operation that gets back $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ from $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$. For this, we need the inverse of the matrix $M$. This is basic linear algebra, and the inverse matrix, represented with bytes again, is 
$$
M^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
0e & 0b & 0d & 09 \\
09 & 0e & 0b & 0d \\
0d & 09 & 0e & 0b \\
0b & 0d & 09 & 0e
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you want more information, you can read the [FIPS-197](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf) standard that describes AES and you can take a look at the book *The Design of Rijndael* from the original authors of the AES algorithm where they give another way to compute the InvMixColumn by using the matrix $M$ from MixColumn with some preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

The MixColumn polynomial is fed through the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, to obtain its inverse.

The MixColumn polynomial is a degree-4 polynomial of degree-8 finite fields, which is equivalent to degree-32 finite field / binary polynomial. And the fact that it's a finite field guarantees the existance of this valid inverse.